# What to call a "string with things attached"?

Tags: phrase-requests

There are a number of idioms around the *string*, that carry the idea that if one pulls it, other things will (or will not) come with it:

> with (no) strings attached
>
> pulling strings
>
> have the world on the string
>
> string together

Conversely, is there an idiom to describe this metaphoric string (contract clause, pressure tactic, discovery) that leads to other things?

> This clause in the contract is the --- that you should watch for.
>
> This discovery is the --- that will lead to many other ones.

Comment: This clause is the "proverbial *string*"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **golden thread**.

> *Following the Golden thread*
>
> The golden thread is a symbol of the inspiration, intuition, and
>   guiding light that graces us throughout our lives. It is that which we
>   follow, knowing that it will, in some mysterious way, guide us on our
>   true paths in life.
>
> It is most colorfully portrayed in Greek mythology as the magical
>   thread that Ariadne gave to Theseus, assisting him in his heroic
>   journey into and out of the Minotaur's labyrinth. As we travel through
>   literal and figurative labyrinths in our lives, the golden thread may
>   easily go unnoticed, yet when it is recognized and followed, we may
>   find that this archetypal strand of gold connects us to our true
>   selves, to our beloveds, and to that which we discover to be home.

[[Patrick Queen; Blogspot](http://the-universe-inside-your-mind.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/following-golden-thread.html)}

> Operational planning is the “golden thread” linking strategy to
>   execution and is ...

[[Joe Evans_EvanCarmichael.com](http://www.evancarmichael.com/library/joe-evans/The-Golden-Thread-Linking-Strategy-to-Execution.html)]

Comment: You're right, in logic it could be an *Ariadne's thread*!